# Overview of statistical maps/charts types

Tags: cartography, statistics, chart

I know of a few ways to visualize statistical information on a map, like choropleth maps, prism maps or simply displaying little bar-charts or pie-charts near locations on a map.

But there must be a lot more different ways to display statistical information on a map. I can only find lists with specific subsets, but no clear overview of all commonly used methods.

Does an overview exist of all commonly used ways to map data to geographic location?

Comment: Maybe you can edit some of your found lists with subsets into the question?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous books on the subject, some very specialized, some very general, and some just examples. One I used in a cartography class, that I would highly recommend for general foundation, is Dent's [Cartography: Thematic Map Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072943823).